# Custom header when requeing

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using SimpleMessageListenerContainer to receive messages from RabbitMq. Is there a way to add custom metadata to a message when it is nack'ed? I would like to continue processing the message from the point it failed.

I'm assuming any exception that gets thrown from a listener will cause the message to be requeued ( provided the exception is setup for that).

Thanks,
Sudha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The amqp protocol only has a simple flag to requeue or not. You can use retry with a subclass of the RepublishMessageRecoverer to add headers, but it will requeue at the tail not the head. See the reference manual.